# jQuery UI Autocomplete Width issue

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

please see this http://jsfiddle.[net]/Nkkzg/108/ (SO doesn't allow to like to JsFiddle) and write 'Apple' in auto-complete text box. You can see a long string appears and with that page's horizontal scroll bar also appear which is very annoying.
I want to show the full string as a result without setting the width, You can see autocomplete results div shows from the left corner to maximum right depending on string length. How can we show the results in the center of page like input textbox, so that horizontal scroll bar shouldn't appear.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: when you add jsFiddle links, you must provide formatted example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `position:absolute`

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border:1px solid #222;
    position:absolute;
  }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkkzg/109/)

Answer (score 2):

According to this article:

[jQuery UI Autocomplete Width Not Set Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643767/jquery-ui-autocomplete-width-not-set-correctly)

It looks as though you need to place everything in a container and specify the `appendTo` property telling it where to put the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put this in your .css file

```
span input.ui-autocomplete-input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

In that way the autocomplete get's the width you have style it to according to the styleClass that is on the enclosing span tag